# How to get cid from market and symbol from google finance

Tags: web, finance, google-finance

I would like to fetch the historical data from [google finance](https://www.google.com/finance).

Url should be like this, this is the link for Apple.

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=22144&startdate=Jan+1%2C+2000&enddate=Jul+30%2C+2017&num=30&ei=bNl9WZC7MNCe0wSR8bw4&output=csv

It requires `cid`

I have symbol name `AAAPL` and market name `NASDAQ` though, I couldn't find how to get the cid `22144` from symbol and market name.

Google finance API is already closed.

How can I get cid number ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain you need the `cid`? I just tried this request to Google Finance:

https://www.google.co.uk/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&ei=k-99WaD9NMSYUsu_moAC&output=csv

This request returned a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to extract historical data for a time period of 1 year from today only then we can use AAPL else we need to provide cid along with the time period

Comment: Hello greentree, there is already an accepted answer to this question...