# How do I get the cid of a stock for Google Finance?

Tags: url, google-finance

While this question was asked beforehand in the following post:

[How to get cid from market and symbol from google finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400175/how-to-get-cid-from-market-and-symbol-from-google-finance)

The answer didn't actually answer the question. Since google finance no longer allows for historical prices beyond a year unless one inputs the appropriate cid into the URL, how does one get the corresponding cid's in order to directly input into the URL the historical prices of specific times? Is there a table available or something along those lines?